# How to open a file which overwrite existing content

Tags: c, linux

I try to open a file like this in linux. It will over-write an existing one if exits. That is what I want.

```
fout = open(out_file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 644);
```

However, if the existing is 1024 bytes, when I open in above way and write 800 new bytes.
I still see the 224 bytes at the end of previous content.

How can I make it just have the 800 bytes that I have been written?

Comment: You're looking for the `O_TRUNC` flag to `open()`.

Comment: You probably don't want mode 644.  Perhaps you do want mode 0644.  But see Ciro's comment about the symbolic names S_xxUSR and so on below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to use the `O_TRUNC` flag to `open()`, by OR-ing it with the existing flags you have above:

```
int fout = open(out_file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 644);
```

This will truncate the file. Below is the information in the man page for open(2).

```
   O_TRUNC
          If the file already exists and is a regular file  and  the  open
          mode  allows  writing  (i.e.,  is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be
          truncated to length 0.  If the file is a FIFO or terminal device
          file,  the  O_TRUNC  flag  is  ignored.  Otherwise the effect of
          O_TRUNC is unspecified.
```

Comment: Use `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` , etc. from `man 2 chmod` instead of `644` ;-)

Comment: What does O_TRUNC do exactly? I couldn't understand from the manpage.

Comment: What don't you understand from the description? I don't know how to make it clearer or less ambiguous.

Comment: The man page you quote, by my reading, implies unspecified behavior if the file already exists.  Seems to work though.  Is it kosher?

Comment: I do see at the end of the man page `creat() is equivalent to open() with flags equal to O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC.`  So I guess it's allowed.